# WebBrowserControl load target URL on same frame

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, webbrowser-control

I have a print button with id "printButton" and the following attribute:

```
onclick=window.open('/path/page.aspx');__doPostBack('printButton','')
```

The code above loads the page on a new window, but I want to load it on the same frame.

I have tried adding several windows as a second parameter in the `window.open` like `'_self'`, `'_parent'` or even replaced the whole with `windows.location.href='/path/page.aspx'`

However none of the above methods worked.

I have even tried `browser.Navigate("target url", "frame");` (after adding a Click event on the button), but this also opens a new page.

Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: Which one? The target page or the current page? I don't have either of those 2. I just know the html that is generated from the source .aspx

Comment: well I wanted to see the source page aspx

Comment: I doesn't matter anyway, but I can't really see how this could help.

Comment: WebBrowserControl, correct? WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried `window.document.location.replace('/path/page.aspx')`?